# Accessing hidden shared/static variables

Tags: .net, scope

With this:

```
  class outer
    public shared X as string = ""
    class inner
      public shared sub test()
        Dim s as string
        s = X ' refers to the shared (static) variable in outer
      end sub
    end class
  end class
```

the reference to X in the test method is to the shared variable declared in the outer class, however, if my inner class declares a variable by that name (eclipsing the shared variable from the outer class), how do I gain access to it?

```
  class outer
    public shared X as string = ""
    class inner
      public X as string = "x"
      public shared sub test()
        Dim s as string
        s = X ' this fails because it's an attempt to access an instance variable
      end sub
    end class
  end class
```

Comment: The inner class has no special relation to the outer, other than having access to the private parts.  It will need a reference to the outer object.

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying the outer class's name, like this:

```vb
Class outer
    Public Shared X As String = "bar"

    Class inner
        Public X As String = "foo"
        Public Shared Sub test()
            Dim s As String = X             ' foo
            Dim t As String = outer.X       ' bar
        End Sub
    End Class
End Class
```

Comment: I had tried that but can't seem to get the syntax right.  the compiler complains: "ERROR:'outer' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level" but I don't get why...

Comment: @ekkis I just tried it and was able to get it to work without any issue. Perhaps `outer` needs to be Public.